# bjt audio amp push pull "super complimentary"

Tags: audio, push-pull

I found here this super complimentary design:
http://www.valveradio.net/audio/super-complementary-stage.html

To improve the symmetry of a complementary push-pull output stage, a special "super complementary" topology can be used which has transistors of both polarities in both legs of the circuit...

It is new for me.

Is "super complimentary" the common name or only valveradio choice ?

Where can I find public manuals about it ?

Comment: ...do you have a question?

Comment: writing at cell phone, be patient please

Comment: Your question is still pretty bad, "where can I find manuals" = google. If you can't find them with google, this is still not a place to ask.

Comment: I am not sure about the circuit name, please help

Comment: @pipe A little trust ? my google-fu cannot find this specific circuit, otherwise I dont ask here !

Comment: @Massimo It has nothing to do with trust. It has all to do with what this website is, what is on-topic, and what is not. It's not a forum for everything related to electronics.

Comment: Removing my downvote at least, because at least there's an actual question now.

Comment: @pipe I read the other questions and if the criteria is "google and/or RTFM ... do not disturb us" ... most of them are off topic. you downvote me : I challenge you to find on internet   docs about this specific circuit

Comment: "super complimentary" is not a common name or even standard one. And from what I know only Bryston use this type of a circuit " Quad-Complementary".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things in audio often have funny names.

"SuperSymmetry" is a patent held by Nelson Pass, btw.

Now, this "super complimentary" topology attempts to make both halves of a push pull emitter follower more identical to each other (ie, more complimentary).

This complicated schematic has huge performance compromises, as it will have a lower voltage excursion, especially in the MOSFET variety. The output won't be able to get as close to the rails as a simple follower.

This means an amplifier with this topology and same RMS power rating as a standard EF amp will be more expensive, due to higher voltage supply, more semiconductors, more aluminium for cooling, etc.

All based on the assumption that the extra cost will give a better result, ie better sound, or better measurements.

It won't. Audio amplifiers spend the majority of their time in the crossover region where both devices are on. Large-signal distortion (ie, what this scheme addresses) only occurs at high power, ie only on peaks, and is irrelevant. It has low harmonic number and is better addressed with higher feedback and smart compensation schemes.

This scheme has no way to turn off the transistors quickly, therefore it is likely to introduce more crossover distortion.

Besides, power semiconductors have large thermal excursions (they heat up) which means any matching between PNP and NPN done at 10mA and 25°C die temperature will be useless when the die temperature swings 50°C up and down on peaks. Matching only holds between semiconductors which dissipate roughly equal powers, for example MOSFETs in parallel. Top and bottom halves of a push pull do not satisfy this condition, thus they can not be matched.

In other words, this topology doesn't seem very useful...

---

EDIT to answer your comment.

I've been considering power amp topologies for my hifi. So first thing I measured the actual current and power necessary to drive my loudspeakers to the levels I like, by sticking a scope at the output of the amp and playing some music (varied tunes with wide differences in dynamic range).

Unsurprisingly, I found out that the amp would stay below 1W most of the time, and only occasionally pump some real power. The 60W RMS amp never ever clipped. It sometimes came close to half peak power on uncompressed drums. To have it clip I would need much lower efficiency speakers (mine are 92dB/1W/1m) or earmuffs.

If you want to build an amp for your speakers, try this measurement first! No need to dish out the cash for an amp with tons of watts you'll never use.

This means any nonlinearity that happens in amps at powers in excess of a few watts is mostly irrelevant. Besides, loudspeakers are very non-linear too, and on peaks, when the loudspeaker cone really moves around, speaker distortion is through the roof anyway. Even our ears have huge THD on powerful peaks. Thus, the schematic you posted tries to fix a problem that exists only in theory.

Consider a single ended class A tube amp. It will have no crossover distortion, very low THD at low power (like 0.1W) yet humongous THD at high power, and still sound excellent provided it is paired with speakers that require very low power, and only make it distort on the occasional peak.

The dangers of trying to fix imaginary problems is that you then miss the real ones!

(This does not apply to nightclub PA amps obviously.)

Comment: Thank you, I am looking for this kind of explanations. Are they only from your know-how  or can you point me to some public docs ? Do you ever build such a circuit and measure the performances or your clues are only  from a theoretical analisys of the circuit ? Sorry but there are so many factors and compromises in circuit design that sometimes there are also good surprises.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is "super complimentary" the common name

Like anything in audio, no terminology is standard or even widely accepted.

Super symmetry generally refers to a topology where the signal travels in the positive and negative cycles are identical or comparable .

For example, a super symmetrical input stage would consist of two differential pairs in parallel but opposite polarity, aka npn and pnp.

The same can be done with the ops, as is show here . the output consists of two diamond buffers, identical to each other. But their driver stage is not symmetrical, one being npn and another pnp.

Comment: ehm ... not very useful, too much generic